# Counting by letters in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, count, letter

**Objective:** count by letters instead of integers.

Is there a clean way to count-by-letters in Python-2.7? I have a program where I am enumerating some data by letter, and my solution would not be very clear to someone reading my code.

I've been checking through the standard documentation, but I don't see anything built-in.

**What I'm looking for:**

```
for count in range('A', 'G'):
    print count

output[1]:
'C'
'D'
'E'
'F'
```

**How I would do it:**

*Solution A:* Use a dictionary

```
letters = {
    1:'A'
    2:'B'
    3:'C'
    ...
}

for count in range(2, 6):
    print letters[count]
```

*Solution B*: Use `chr()` and `ord()`

```
for count in range(2, 6):
    print chr(ord('A') + count)
```

**Relevance:**

I am working on a sunday paper crytogram solver. Part of my algorithm involves classifying words by their letter code. For example,

```
print letter_code('banana')
output[2]: 'ABCBCB'
```

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase` or `string.ascii_uppercase` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *Solution B* could be expressed:

```
for charcode in range(ord('B'), ord('G')):
    print chr(charcode)
```

But to attack your larger issue, how about:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

def letter_code(string):
    indexes = [ascii_lowercase.index(letter) for letter in string]
    return "".join(ascii_uppercase[indexes.index(number)] for number in indexes)

print letter_code('banana')
```

Gives you "ABCBCB"

Comment: Nice! Still trying to figure out the mechanics behind the `"".join(...` line, but really nice and concise.

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase

>>> for char in alphabet[2:6]:
...     print char
...     
C
D
E
F
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that would do what you wish:

```
import string

def enumerate(first, last):
    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
    start = alphabet.index(first)
    while alphabet[start] != last:
        print alphabet[start]
        start += 1
    print last
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I have become fond of for my particular application is:

```
alphabet = iter('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
print next(alphabet)
```